# Added a node to a graph connected via prompt with py2neo but MATCH (n) RETURN (n) shows empty graph in Neo4j browser

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am moving the first steps with py2neo.

I have created a graph via Neo4j Desktop

> DBMS Name: Neo4j
>
> password: Neo4j

and I have started it. Then I opened it with Neo4j browser, where it shows I am connected as user `neo4j` to `bolt://localhost:7687`.

[image]

Then, I connected to it from my prompt by typing

```
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", user="neo4j", password="Neo4j")

>>> graph
Graph('bolt://neo4j@localhost:7687')
```

I created a node

```
nicole = Node("person", name="Nicole", age=24)

>>> nicole
Node('person', age=24, name='Nicole')
```

and then I in my Neo4j browser, I expect to see my node if I type the query:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN (n)
```

But it returns nothing.

1. Why?
2. Also, if in my Chrome browser URL Bar I type `http://localhost:7474/`, it returns the same view of the Neo4j browser ( `MATCH (n) RETURN (n)` does not work even here )

[image]

but  if in my Chrome browser URL Bar I type  `http://localhost:7687/`, it returns a void window with just the message

> not a WebSocket handshake request: missing upgrade

Why I don't get a Neo4j-browser-like view even in this second case?

Comment: you have just created an object. To create the node in graph, you need to execute graph.create(nicole).

Comment: Thanks @Rajat, type it as answer and I will flag it as correct.

Comment: thanks.. i have added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use the `graph.create()` to save the object in the database.

```
graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", user="neo4j", password="Neo4j")

>>> graph
Graph('bolt://neo4j@localhost:7687')
nicole = Node("person", name="Nicole", age=24)

>>> nicole
Node('person', age=24, name='Nicole')

>>> graph.create(nicole)
```

You can read more [here](https://py2neo.org/2.0/essentials.html#py2neo.Graph.create)

Answer (score 1):

Your code simply creates a local node. To create it in the graph, use:

```
graph.create(nicole)
```

Then it will appear in your browser query.